# if val is more or equal to 0 how to round it off to the nearest integer?

Tags: java

`val` is double but it wants to be rounded off to an integer. Can someone point me in the right direction? Also, I cannot use math libraries.

```
public int roundOff(double val) {
    
    if(val>=0) { 
    val = (roundOff(val));
    }
  return 0; 
}
```

***P.S.** I cannot use `Math`*

Comment: According to Jane cannot use `Math`, this question is not a duplicate. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Do look at:

```java
Math.round();
Math.ceil();
Math.floor();
```

And select what you need. These methods have a bit different round strategy.

***P.S.** This should work if you cannot use `Math`. This is not a precise solution, but it works for 99% of cases.*

```java
public static int roundToNearestInt(double val) {
    double mid = (int)val + .5;

    if (Double.compare(val, mid) < 0)
        return (int)val;

    return (int)val + 1;
}
```

**Output:**

```
4.00 -> 4
4.10 -> 4
4.50 -> 5
4.70 -> 5
```

Comment: I cannot use math libraries. Is there another way?

Comment: @user16320675 Yep, I have voted to reopen it. Looks like this is not a duplicate, according to not using `Math`.